# Will I require a transit visa to travel to Antigua from Gatwick

Tags: visas, transit

I will be travelling to Antigua to cover the first cricket test match between India and West Indies.

Will I require a transit visa as I have to change airport from Heathrow to Gatwick, as my flight to Antigua is from Gatwick?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to apply for a "Visitor in Transit visa"

> Leaving the airport Apply for a Visitor in Transit visa if you’ll be
>   going through UK border control but leaving the UK within 48 hours.
>
> You can also apply for a long-term Visitor in Transit visa if you can
>   prove you need to frequently pass through the UK over a longer period.
>
> Fees Direct Airside Transit visa (DATV) - £32  Visitor in Transit visa
>   - £59

please refer to the following link and note the cost may vary (still that is mentioned on the uk gov website)

[Visa to pass through the UK in transit](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/overview)

Comment: Hi Newton, welcome to Travel.SE and thank you for your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged here because they can change over time; it is much better to answer with the necessary information here and just refer to the link as a reference. Could you edit your answer with that in mind? Thank you!

Comment: whoops. sorry about that